Intl.NumberFormat alter minus symbol
I've read through the Intl.NumberFormat docs and can't find a simple way to achieve something.
I want to use a custom character for the minus symbol:
− instead of -
(UNICODE &#8722; instead of ASCII Code &#45;)
for screen reader reasons.
I don't see an option to do this in the Intl.NumberFormat - is there a way to change the character for currency formatting as part of the options?
Or is simply tagging a replace onto the end the best approach?

To put it very plainly, there is not a way to change the - to an − within the Intl.NumberFormat.  Just tag on a .replace('-', '−') at the end of the Intl.NumberFormat and you'll be good.
